# Webview scrolling on Android not working properly

Tags: android, webview, attributes, scrollview

In the webview.xml, I only have a frame layout as a wrapper for the webView as the following,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/scroll_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

As a little background of the webview, it's basically a mobile web page that displays pictures, and allows for horizontal scrolling(either swiping or clicking the 'next' button). Right now, I'm able to scroll to the next photo via swiping, but once I release my finger, the photo pops back to the original photo. Same thing is happening for clicking next, the screen displays half of the next photo before scrolling back to the previous photo.

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening as I've tried all options with playing with the horizontal scrolling attributes, but it still isn't working. Could anyone who has experienced this provide some insights. Please feel free to let me know what additional info you need.

Answer (score 0):

try using linear layout rather than using frame layout as you have only one child that is webview for the parent layout.

this one works for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry I didn't mention the rest of the layout, but the frame layout is also wrapped in a relative layout!